# Avoid Excel replacing path in formula

Tags: excel-formula, path

I know it's a recurring question, but I haven't found an answer yet... My issue is that a formula that contains a path in Excel it's being updated under the following two events:

- Opening that file from another laptop connected on the same net. Then the path changes from: 'D:\files...' to '\LAPTOP1\files...'
- The second case is when laptop reboots (for example after a Windows update). Then the path becomes something like: 'C:\Users\john\AppData...'

The formula I'm using is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT('D:\files\excel01.xlsm'!ITEMS*('D:\files\excel01.xlsm'!ITEM_id=$C26))
```

I know the possibility of using INDIRECT but the problem is that it returns #REF when searched files are closed. Using SUMPRODUCT I can retrieve values from closed workbooks, but I would also keep paths as they are written.

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: could write a little VBA routine that fires ON OPEN event that goes to the appriate cells and adjusts the path to what its supposed to be.

Comment: Hi Ed, the thing is that every time I replace the path it takes so long time as the sheet contains lots of cells with paths... I don't know if another solution could be to "freeze" somehow the operation that updates the path.